# magento frontend and admin panel is not working properly

Tags: installation

please visit this link : http://gas2.newtrendzonline.com/ma_deluxe_quickstart/

it's not displaying properly and it's admin too:  http://gas2.newtrendzonline.com/ma_deluxe_quickstart/admin/

please give me solution for both.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store and report back with more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your base url in core_config_data tabel

Comment: yes, i checked core _ config_ table  it . i folows this link : its fine : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/magento-installation-not-displaying-frontend-and-admin-panel/35255?noredirect=1#comment48290_35255

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks a lot @R.S this is all because of your answer here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/magento-installation-not-displaying-frontend-and-admin-panel/35255?noredirect=1#comment48290_35255